# Неизвестный тип вывода CalledProcessError

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, кодировка, subprocess

Пытаюсь отловить исключение, возникающее при вызове команды cd (Windows 10). переменная exc.output представляет из себя что-то вроде `'b\x8d\xa5\xa2\xa5\xe0\xad\xae \xa7\xa0\xa4\xa0\xad\xae \xa8\xac\xef \xaf\xa0\xaf\xaa\xa8.\r\n'`, как конвертировать данную строку в человеко читаемый текст?

```
import subprocess

def run_cd(args=''):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(['cd', f'{args}'], 
                                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                          shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        print('error catched')
        print(exc.output)
    else:
        return output.decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: @gil9red, я это уже испробовал, не спасает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указывать кодировку консоли `windows` – `cp866`

```
print(exc.output.decode("cp866"))
```

Проверка кодировки:

```
data = b'\x8d\xa5\xa2\xa5\xe0\xad\xae \xa7\xa0\xa4\xa0\xad\xae \xa8\xac\xef \xaf\xa0\xaf\xaa\xa8.\r\n'
print(data.decode('cp866'))
# Неверно задано имя папки.
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyPetrov, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)